# How to save the current view matrix using pyglet

Tags: python, opengl, pyglet, opengl-compat

I am using pyglet and want to have a function that can draw a color to the background of the scene. I am currently just drawing a rectangle to the screen that goes from the bottom left to the top right. This works great until I start applying transformations. For instance if I use the Rotate command the 'background' rectangle gets rotated as well

I have tried using glGetFloatv to get the current matrix, reset it to the identity, then reset it back.

```py
a = (GLfloat * 16)() # do something?
modelMat = glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, a) # save matrix
glLoadIdentity() # reset matrix
x1, y1, x2, y2 = 0, 0, self.width, self.height # get the coords
# self.width / self.height give the width and height of the screen
quad = pyglet.graphics.vertex_list(4,
    ('v2i', (x1, y1,  x2, y1, x2, y2, x1, y2)),
    ('c4B', (
    r, g, b, a, 
    r, g, b, a, 
    r, g, b, a, 
    r, g, b, a))
    ) # define the rectangle
quad.draw(GL_QUADS) # draw rectangle
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA) # do alpha
glMultMatrixf(modelMat) # reset matrix
```

This code returns this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jakemonsky/Development/pythonApps/PygletTest/main.py", line 34, in <module>
    APP.run()
  File "/Users/jakemonsky/Development/pythonApps/PygletTest/processing.py", line 364, in run
    pyglet.app.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyglet/app/__init__.py", line 138, in run
    event_loop.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyglet/app/base.py", line 142, in run
    self._run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyglet/app/base.py", line 154, in _run
    timeout = self.idle()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyglet/app/base.py", line 281, in idle
    window.dispatch_event('on_draw')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyglet/window/__init__.py", line 1232, in dispatch_event
    if EventDispatcher.dispatch_event(self, *args) != False:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyglet/event.py", line 371, in dispatch_event
    event_type, args, getattr(self, event_type))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyglet/event.py", line 367, in dispatch_event
    if getattr(self, event_type)(*args):
  File "/Users/jakemonsky/Development/pythonApps/PygletTest/processing.py", line 223, in on_draw
    self.bind_draw(dt)
  File "/Users/jakemonsky/Development/pythonApps/PygletTest/processing.py", line 41, in __call__
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jakemonsky/Development/pythonApps/PygletTest/main.py", line 14, in draw
    Background(0,0,0,255)
  File "/Users/jakemonsky/Development/pythonApps/PygletTest/processingLocalizer.py", line 62, in Background
    Application.Background(r, g, b, a)
  File "/Users/jakemonsky/Development/pythonApps/PygletTest/processing.py", line 449, in Background
    r, g, b, a))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyglet/graphics/__init__.py", line 292, in vertex_list
    return _get_default_batch().add(count, 0, None, *data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyglet/graphics/__init__.py", line 372, in add
    vlist._set_attribute_data(i, array)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyglet/graphics/vertexdomain.py", line 443, in _set_attribute_data
    region.array[:] = data
TypeError: incompatible types, c_float_Array_16 instance instead of c_ubyte instance
[Finished in 2.3s with exit code 1]
```

I am not sure what is causing this or if I am even approaching this problem correctly. I am very new to openGL and pyglet and not sure what is happening under the hood to cause this error. Is there a better way to 'reset' the transformations or a way to draw something to the screen in screen space instead of transformed space that I am missing?

EDIT:
The error is because I am stupidly reusing a for the matrix (also my alpha channel) but now I just get the output

```
2019-07-05 11:03:46.789 Python[853:21283] ApplePersistenceIgnoreState: Existing state will not be touched. New state will be written to (null)
[Finished in 2.1s with exit code -11]
```

when the command is called and the program just ends. OSX also pops up a window asking if it closed properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to save the current view matrix using pyglet

There is a stack of matrices for the current matrix. A matrix can be pushed to and popped from the stack by [`glPushMatrix` `glPopMatrix`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glPushMatrix.xml).

Push the matrix before the transformation and pop it after:

```py
glPushMatrix()

glLoadIdentity() # reset matrix
x1, y1, x2, y2 = 0, 0, self.width, self.height # get the coords
# self.width / self.height give the width and height of the screen
quad = pyglet.graphics.vertex_list(4,
    ('v2i', (x1, y1,  x2, y1, x2, y2, x1, y2)),
    ('c4B', (
    r, g, b, a, 
    r, g, b, a, 
    r, g, b, a, 
    r, g, b, a))
    ) # define the rectangle
quad.draw(GL_QUADS) # draw rectangle
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA) # do alpha

glPopMatrix()
```

Note there is a stack of matrices for each matrix mode (`GL_MODELVIEW`, `GL_PROJECTION`, `GL_TEXTURE` and `GL_COLOR`). See [`glMatrixMode`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glMatrixMode.xml).

---

The error is caused, because [`glGetFloatv`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glGet.xml) doesn't return any value. It reads the matrix to the memory which is passed to the function.
You've to pass the array to [`glMultMatrixf`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glMultMatrix.xml)

```py
modelMat = (GLfloat * 16)()
glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelMat) # read to array "modelMat"
glLoadIdentity() 

# [...]

glMultMatrixf(modelMat) # multiply matrix in the array "modelMat"
```

Note, as the name indicates, `glMultMatrixf` multiplies the matrix to the current matrix. This works in your case, because the current matrix is the [Identity matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix). A matrix can be loaded to the current matrix by [`glLoadMatrix`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glLoadMatrix.xml).

Comment: Ah thanks!  I knew I could push / pop but I had thought the ```glLoadIdentity()``` command reset the matrix, good to know that it just adds to the stack.

Comment: @Jmonsky Your original idea works, too. See the 2nd part of the answer.